# I can't get elementById value (Fiddle added)

Tags: getelementbyid

I'm trying to get the value of several IDs (test0, test1, test2....). I've already tried to use [id^="test"], but it seems that it's the getelementById that is not working, even if I use :

```
document.getElementById('test0').value;
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/443502/
I just want to get the text in the span.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine, the only issue is that divs do not have a value property, therefore you get 'undefined'

Comment: Damn, I have just spent more than 2 hours troubleshooting. I was wrong about the "value" function. How can I get the text inside the spans? Thank you for your help

Comment: How about: alert(document.getElementById('term0').textContent);

Comment: Please note you have multiple nodes with the same id, this is incorrect. Please make them unique to avoid trouble

Comment: Yeah I know, That was an error I realized after I was pretty advanced in my code. Your code worked but when I use [id^="test"] to select the text in test0 and test1 it stops working.

Comment: there is nothing with id='test' in the document so how do you expect it to work?

Comment: With my limited knowledge, as far as I know [id^="test"] stands for id attribute starts with test. Am I mistaken? I wan to extract all the testx .textContent.

Comment: TBH I've never seen that in my life... but I think this should do the trick for you: alert(document.getElementById('test1').textContent);

That will return all the text without any HTML inside the div with id test1

Comment: I got that sorted with your first answer, what I want is to extract the text that is in id testx (test0 and test1 in my example), hence the [id^="test"].